# Toggling amongst plot spaces

Tags: plot, core-plot, scatter-plot

**Scenario:** Five Graphs for Five Periods {3M, 6M, 1Y, 2Y & 3Y}, each with their own (1-2) scatter plots; sharing the same y-range (values).

Each period has different x-ranges and labeling policies.

For example, one could have either a fix or location policy; another none.

The X-Range appears to be *immutable*/plot-space. 
 So I'm thinking of creating parallel plot spaces with their particular xRanges & labeling policies.

I studied the relationship of a plot space with the x.axis(s) & plot(s):

Graph <=== {NSMutableArray *plotSpaces}

x.axis/plot-space.

plot/plot-space

So I believe I can:

1) Create a plotspace.

2) Assign the plotspace to a particular plot, x-axis & xRange.

3) add or remove the plot to/from the graph.

4) Redraw the graph.

So when the user selects a period/plotspace, All I need to do is: replace any existing plots with the period plot(s) which will cause the graph to plot the plots & display the respective x-axis (Y-axis is common)?

```
[myGraph removePlot:(CPTPlot *)oldPlot];
[myGraph addPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot toPlotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space];
```

...I'm a little lost here.

?

Answer (score 0):

Axes are also assigned to a plot space. You would need to swap out the axes, too. You'll take a relatively large performance hit by adding and removing plots and axes all the time.

As you observed, the plot ranges are immutable. That just means that you can't change an existing range, not that you can't set a new one. Either create a new `CPTPlotRange` object or make a mutable copy of an existing one.

Whenever you want to change the plot scale, you need to do the following things. These can all change in place, without removing and replacing major pieces of the graph.

1. Change the plot ranges as described above.
2. Update the labeling policy and related properties of the axis.
3. Call `-reloadData` on the plot to load the new data.

Comment: I attempted to replace the old xRange with a new one:

`CPTPlotRange *myXRange = [[CPTPlotRange alloc]initWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(1)];
    plotSpace.xRange = myXRange;
    [myXRange release];`

...using a '1' to see if I make a difference.

But alas, I see no difference in the range; even after doing a graph reloadData.

Comment: That's the default range. Try something else. :-)

Comment: Can you please be more specific?   I thought that I could replace the plotSpace's xRange with a non-default xRange as I've tried.  That is, I've created a range @ location & length; then assigned it to the current (de facto) plot space.  What should I do differently?

Comment: The default plot ranges have a location of zero (0) and length (1). If  you set a new range with the same values, nothing will change. Can you edit your question and add some of your code? It would help to see how you are configuring the plot space and axes, and how you are changing the new ranges.

Comment: Odd, I had submitted it yesterday and was 'on hold' for peer review.  It appears they rejected it without informing me.   I'll rephrase and try again later today.

Comment: Okay, I resubmitted:
"Thanks for your edit!
This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed."